# Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create() - laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Maatwebsite/Excel in my application and when i get the error

> > Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()

from one of my controllers.  I am using laravel 5.6 and i have followed the documentation strictly and other very few related discussions online to solve this, but i still get the error.

How do i solve this error please

**app.php**

```
'provider' => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',

'alias' => 'Excel'=>  'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',
```

**Controller**

```
$cl = ClassModel::Select('name')->where('code',$input->class)->first();
        $input->class=$cl->name;
        $fileName=$input->class.'-'.$input->section.'-'.$input->session.'-'.$input->exam;
        // return $students;
        Excel::create($fileName, function($excel) use($input,$subjects,$students) {
            $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) use ($input,$subjects,$students) {
                $sheet->loadView('app.excel',compact('subjects','input','students'));
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
```

Comment: which version use for Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd maatwebsite/excel": "~3.0

Comment: Please update 3.0 to 2.0 and try

Comment: Version 3.0 of that package doesn't handle imports yet. Release date for this feature is unknown. See this post for more details: https://medium.com/@maatwebsite/laravel-excel-lessons-learned-7fee2812551

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to decrease the version using :

```
composer require "maatwebsite/excel=2.1.0"
```

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
  Could not find package ~2.1.0 at any version for your minimum-stability (de  
  v). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

Answer (score 3):

You are using 2.* syntax while using 3.* package. Please refer to the correct documentation over here: https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/export/basics

Comment: Per documentation: "Excel::create() is removed and replaced by Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)"

Answer (score 0):

There have been many changes in the new version of the package.

In your `composer.json` file inside the require array replace your package with this:

`"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",`

and then run `composer update`
This should work fine.

Comment: composer update! Isn't this going to update all his dependencies?

Comment: Definitely good, but the intention was not to update all dependencies. Anyway since its still in development, there might not be worries. Otherwise, I'll safely install the dependency individually. Or rather, remove my vendor folder and rerun `composer install`

Comment: is removing vendor folder a good practice? @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Comment: 'good' practice could be relative, the vendor folder changes anyways through out the development changes. So yes, if there's a need to remove 'vendor' folder one can do so, simply running `composer install` would generate back the vendor folder based on the specification in the composer.lock or composer.json file(s)

Answer (score 0):

Please switch to version 2*

Version 3.0 of that package doesn't handle imports yet. Release date for this feature is unknown. See this post for more details: [maatwebsite](https://medium.com/@maatwebsite/laravel-excel-lessons-learned-7fee2812551)

Comment: When i switch to version 2, i get this error in the terminal  Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.6.7

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it around but I know it's not a perfect solution. It will really help you if you only have concerns with the uploading not *adjusting* Crudbooster features.

1. I removed the extra features from the importing screen of the Crudbooster by applying the following CSS in the crudbooster-controller.

   ```
        $this->style_css = "ul.nav li:not(:first-child) {
            display: none;
        }";
   ```
2. I copied the getImportData() method from Crudbooster CBController and overridden it in the crudbooster-controller by the following code.

```js
//PHP
//By the way, you can still create your own method in here... :)

public function getImportData()
        {
            $this->cbLoader();
            $data['page_menu'] = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName();
            $data['page_title'] = 'Import Data';

            if (request('file') && ! request('import')) {
                $file = base64_decode(request('file'));
                $file = storage_path('app/'.$file);

                $data = Excel::import(new ProductImport, $file);

                CRUDBooster::redirect('/admin/products', cbLang("alert_add_data_success"), 'success');
            }

            return view('crudbooster::import', $data);

        }
```

**Importing is working fine now**